# Socket.io Middle-ware

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I am wondering how can i make socket.io avail outside my app.js page. I have currently all my socket related code on the app.js page after

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const socketio = require('socket.io
const expressServer = app.listen(9999);
const io = socketio(expressServer);
```

where i can use the io.xxx  but what i rather would do is to initialize the socket.io and then put all related code into a separate file where i can then expose functions to call emits etc.

Comment: Export a function that allows other modules to import and call to get access to the `io` instance.  Or put all the socket.io code in another module that exports the `io` instance via a function call and your app module imports and calls an initialization method passing it the server is should bind to.  This is just another exercise in module design/sharing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put the socket.io code in it's own module and use exports to initialize and share the instance.

**sio.js**

```
const socketio = require('socket.io');
let io;

module.exports = {
   init: function(server) {
        if (io) {
            throw new Error("socket.io already initialized");
        }
        // initalize socket.io to this server
        io = socketio(server);

        // put other socket.io initialization code here

        return io;
   }
   get: function() {
        if (!io) {
             throw new Error("socket.io has not yet been initialized");
        }
        return io;
   }
}
```

**app.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const expressServer = app.listen(9999);
const io = require('sio').init(expressServer);
```

**some other module file that wants access to socket.io instance**

```
const io = require('sio').get();
```

This allows one socket.io instance bound to one server per process (because the `io` instance is stored in module data).  It could be extended to support multiple instances for multiple servers, but you'd then have to say which server you wanted the instance for when requesting the instance.

Note also that the `.init()` method must be called before the `.get()` can be called so the sio module should be loaded and call `.init()` on it early in the app module's setup before it loads other things that themselves might want to load sio.

Comment: That works like a charm now i can get access to the socket from any other module. One question i have is where would i put the basic socket stuff if i dont want it in the app.js like io.on('connect')

Comment: i guess i can just put it in a separate file and make it required in the app and since the socket.io is like a its own middle ware when you use io.on... it should not matter since the code is not route specific

Comment: @NoSoup4you - You can put `io.on('connect', ...)` either in sio.js where is says "put other socket.io initialization code here" or in it's own file that you can then import sio.js into.  Personally, I'd leave sio.js as is because you can reuse it in other projects and then put this app's socket.io code in it's own module that imports sio.js.

Comment: i took your second approach, use the sio only to get the socket setup and then put the general stuff like handling connect and disconnect and db interaction in a separate file

Comment: What is the best way to ensure that the .init completed before another file is loaded that wants to get the io reference ? I tried your approach with 2 seperate files, the sio and then i had a file called socket all works fine on a dev machine which has only a few files but when i go and try on the prod server which has 20 + route files 30 + helper a bunch of controllers etc to load i get the error that the socket.io has not been init yet

Comment: @NoSoup4you - It should be easy to control from your main app module.  Just load `sio.js` and call `.init()` before any other modules that want access to `sio.js` are loaded.  I suppose you could also make `.get()` return a promise that resolves when `.init()` is called and then have everyone else use that promise to get access to `io`, but that makes all those other modules have to program for async access to `io` and is not as convenient.  I'd prefer to just have your main app file load and init `sio.js` before anything else gets loaded that could possibly use it.

Comment: @NoSoup4you - The loading and initializing of `sio.js` is entirely synchronous (no async callbacks involved) so it should be simple to order things appropriately.

Comment: what if i want to receive a event in a module?. Using socket.on('event') i get socket not defined, because im not using io, but if the connection its established, i only need to use socket @jjriend00

Comment: i think this not need to use io.on connection socket bla bla in every module, im i right?

Comment: @AlexHunter - There's no generic way to answer that as it depends upon exactly what you're trying to do and how your code is organized.  Please post your own question that shows how your code is structured and describes exactly what you're trying to do.

Comment: I'm following the same code that is post here. And then I create a module.js where I need to listen a socket event

Comment: @AlexHunter - If you don't already have the `socket` you want to listen to or you want to listen for the event on all newly created sockets, then you have to find or add an `io.on('connection', ...)` because that's the only place that new sockets are presented to you so you can add your listener.   If you need any more help than that, please post your own question with your specific code.  It's perfectly fine to have multiple `io.on('connection', ...)` handlers across files.

Comment: Excellent response @jjfriend are sure that's not a bad practice to use multiple times on connection event? Because Im going to create 10 modules, and every module receive and emit events to some client

Comment: @AlexHunter - It's not a bad practice to use more than one.  If you're doing 10, all in separate modules, I might wonder about whether your code is organized into modules in the best way, but that would just be a personal design opinion.